# Check if a map is subset of another map

Tags: dictionary, go, generics, reflection, go-map

This question is already answered in many other languages. In golang with simple maps (no nesting) how to find out if a map is subset of another. for example: `map[string]string{"a": "b", "e": "f"}` is subset of `map[string]string{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}`. I want a generic method. My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    a := map[string]string{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}
    b := map[string]string{"a": "b", "e": "f"}
    c := IsMapSubset(a, b)
    fmt.Println(c)
}

func IsMapSubset(mapSet interface{}, mapSubset interface{}) bool {

    mapSetValue := reflect.ValueOf(mapSet)
    mapSubsetValue := reflect.ValueOf(mapSubset)

    if mapSetValue.Kind() != reflect.Map || mapSubsetValue.Kind() != reflect.Map {
        return false
    }
    if reflect.TypeOf(mapSetValue) != reflect.TypeOf(mapSubsetValue) {
        return false
    }
    if len(mapSubsetValue.MapKeys()) == 0 {
        return true
    }

    iterMapSubset := mapSubsetValue.MapRange()

    for iterMapSubset.Next() {
        k := iterMapSubset.Key()
        v := iterMapSubset.Value()

        if value := mapSetValue.MapIndex(k); value == nil || v != value { // invalid: value == nil
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

When I want to check if subset map key exists in set map, `MapIndex` returns zero value of type and make it impossible to compare it with anything.

Afterall can I do the same job better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Value.MapIndex()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MapIndex) returns a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) which is a struct, and `nil` is not a valid value for structs. You can't compare a struct value to `nil`.

`Value.MapIndex()` states that:

> It returns the zero Value if key is not found in the map or if v represents a nil map.

So to tell if the key was not found in the map, check if the returned `reflect.Value` is its zero value. For that you may use the [`Value.IsValid()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsValid) method.

You also can't (shouldn't) compare `reflect.Value` values. Instead obtain their wrapped value using [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface), and compare those.

```
if v2 := mapSetValue.MapIndex(k); !v2.IsValid() || v.Interface() != v2.Interface() {
    return false
}
```

Testing it:

```
a := map[string]string{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}
b := map[string]string{"a": "b", "e": "f"}
fmt.Println(IsMapSubset(a, b))

c := map[string]string{"a": "b", "e": "X"}
fmt.Println(IsMapSubset(a, c))
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/BIlPSbvXVXp)):

```
true
false
```

Comment: This does not seem to apply to the case where the [keys of the map are different](https://go.dev/play/p/19TCmNHeRyX).

Comment: Use `!v2.isValid()` to pass my test cases in the previous comment

Comment: @moluzhui Yes, you're right. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> I want a generic method.

Now that Go 1.18 and generics are here, you can write such a generic function; see below and in this [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/caycwp-eeHH). Reflection, [which is generally discouraged](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=15m23s), is not required to implement this functionality.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func IsMapSubset[K, V comparable](m, sub map[K]V) bool {
    if len(sub) > len(m) {
        return false
    }
    for k, vsub := range sub {
        if vm, found := m[k]; !found || vm != vsub {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

type MyMap map[string]string

func main() {
    a := map[string]string{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}
    b := map[string]string{"a": "b", "e": "f"}
    c := map[string]string{"a": "b", "e": "g"}
    fmt.Println(IsMapSubset(a, b))
    fmt.Println(IsMapSubset(a, c))
    fmt.Println(IsMapSubset(MyMap(a), c))
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

[The usual caveats about `NaN`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20660) apply, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working solution in case anyone needs:

```
// IsMapSubset returns true if mapSubset is a subset of mapSet otherwise false
func IsMapSubset(mapSet interface{}, mapSubset interface{}) bool {

    mapSetValue := reflect.ValueOf(mapSet)
    mapSubsetValue := reflect.ValueOf(mapSubset)

    if fmt.Sprintf("%T", mapSet) != fmt.Sprintf("%T", mapSubset) {
        return false
    }

    if len(mapSetValue.MapKeys()) < len(mapSubsetValue.MapKeys()) {
        return false
    }

    if len(mapSubsetValue.MapKeys()) == 0 {
        return true
    }

    iterMapSubset := mapSubsetValue.MapRange()

    for iterMapSubset.Next() {
        k := iterMapSubset.Key()
        v := iterMapSubset.Value()

        value := mapSetValue.MapIndex(k)

        if !value.IsValid() || v.Interface() != value.Interface() {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```